# iPhone OTA giving error

Tags: iphone

I have an html page which points to a plist file and the plist file actually has the correct .ipa file. When I try to click on the link on the page which points to the plist. I get cannot connect to server error. The same thing works if I move it to a different server and that has http:// but for some reasons it doesn't work on https. I'm using tomcat as my application server. Any clues why ?

Comment: I found the reason. The https site had an self signed certificate and hence the issue. So people who have issues with OTA using https site. Please make sure to have a valid certificate. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the reason. The https site had an self signed certificate and hence the issue. So people who have issues with OTA using https site. Please make sure to have a valid certificate. Hope this helps –

Comment: What do you mean a valid certificate? What does one have to do to change it up so OTA will work?

Comment: If you have a site which uses https and has slef-signed certificate the app doesn't download. If you have a a valid certificate from a certificate authority and use that, it works. This is an SSL certificate issue nothing to do with apple developer certificate

Comment: After you wrote this I got a number of people confirming that. Strange thing is, according to apple you can do it:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/profile-service/profile-service.html

Relevant section: "Alternatively, you can generate your own root certificate and self-sign it, though if you do, the user will be asked whether they trust the certificate."

Is this a mistake on Apple's part?

Comment: I have never seen the message where safari is asking me to trust this certificate. I don't know whether its a mistake on Apples part ? It would be a good question for Apple though. I'm just giving my first hand experience and the fix here.

Comment: You're worked with a self-signed cert and it didn't ask for permission? All the other forums I've visited said that's what happens, as a lot of phishing sites use those.

Comment: I tried accessing the site on the safari browser on iPhone OS and I didn't get any message for permission. I still access the site from my phone and don't see browser asking for permission. I deleted the cache and history. It may be an issue with iOS. I'm on 4. They may have fixed it in 5 or 6. Since most of our users use 4, that's what I was concerned about